# Angularjs - navbar dropdown menu getting overlapped inside ui-layout

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to figure out why NavBar drop-down getting overlapped inside `ui-layout`. This seems very basic and am definitely missing some very basic steps.

Check the plunker for issue details : https://plnkr.co/edit/SpdVc6biwWg5PqfaSfgS?p=preview

I have looked all over the web and tried `z-index`, `overflow:hidden` and other small hecks.

Comment: Thanks for the Plunker, but also provide your code in your question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the overflow value on div ui-layout-container

Change this

```
<div ui-layout-container size="10%" >
```

And add 'overflow:visible' to the style

```
<div ui-layout-container size="10%" style="overflow:visible" >
```

Comment: Love You :) You made my day. Thanks !